# How to formulate angular nested array object

Tags: arrays, angular, postman

I have an entity relationship where 1 hotel can have many contract and 1 contract can have many rooms.

For that purpose I used the below code.

```
  hotel : Hotels = new Hotels();
  //contractsList: Contract;


  public userData:Contract[] = [{
    start_date:new Date(),
    end_date:new Date,
    room_type:RoomType[{
      id:0,
      name:'',
      max_adults:0,
      max_rooms:0,
      price:0
    }]
```

[image: error]
However, its not allowing me to assign in this way.

So the basic request format should be like:

```
{
"hotel_name":"name",
"hotel_email":"hotel@gmail.com",
"contractList":[{
             "start_date": "2020-12-2",
             "end-date":"2020-12-10",
             "roomsList":[{
                   //room details
                 }]
}]
}
```

The HTML code

```
form #addressForm="ngForm" class ="text-center border border-light p-5" (ngSubmit)="logValue()">
  <p class="h4 mb-4">Enter hotel details</p>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-6">

    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-4" name = "name" [(ngModel)]=" hotel.name" placeholder="Enter hotel name"/>
    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-4" name = "email" [(ngModel)]=" hotel.email" placeholder="Enter hotel email"/>
    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-4" name = "address1" [(ngModel)]=" hotel.address1" placeholder="Enter hotel address line 1"/>
    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-4" name = "address2" [(ngModel)]=" hotel.address2" placeholder="Enter hotel address line 2"/>


    <br><br>
    
    <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2" [ngStyle]="{align:'left'}" type="button" (click)="addContract()">Add CONTRACT</button> 

    <!-- some code here - see full code at the end of this tutorial -->
     <section class ="container border mb-4 p-3" *ngFor="let item of userData; let i = index;">
        <!-- input fields inside the *ngFor -->
        <div class="form-row mb-4">
          <div class="col">
           <label>Start Date</label>
           <input type="date"  class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="item.start_date"
             name="startDate_{{i}}"/>
             </div>
             <div class="col">

             <label>End Date</label>
           <input type="date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="item.end_date"
             name="endDate_{{i}}"/>
            </div>
            </div>
       
     </section>
</form>
```

I am not sure how to include the rooms details with contract

The TS file

```
logValue() {
    console.log(this.userData);
    this.hotel.contractList= this.userData;
}
```

through this method i am attempting to assign the contract array to the contractList variable of the hotel

Comment: can you share how your datatype for Contract and RoomType look like?

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to use `RoomType` as a class, however this is a datatype so you could do something like this instead:

```
interface Contract {
    start_date: Date;
    end_date: Date;
    room_type: RoomType;
}

interface RoomType {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    max_adults: number;
    max_rooms: number;
    price: number;
}

class MyClass {
    userData: Contract[] = [
        {
            start_date: new Date(),
            end_date: new Date(),
            room_type: {
                id: 0,
                name: '',
                max_adults: 1,
                max_rooms: 2,
                price: 123
            }
        }
    ];
}
```